# arcgis javascript api api merge/dissolve two polygons

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am have a feature service with differnt cities in  Ontario. The polygons are editable on client side and I would like to have an ability to merge two adjacent polygons into one. So technically advanced editing of polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I would fetch the feature geometries and use the geometry Union tool of a Geometry Service (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#union) to merge the geometries, then post the new geometry back to the Feature Service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use geometryEngine module added in 3.13 https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html